# Django select one row from related model set

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Lets say, i have the following model configurations in **models.py:**

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    columnA = models.ForeignKey(ModelZ)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    columnB = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, related_name='modelsets')
    is_open = models.BooleanField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I know i can select all the ModelA objects and all the related ModelB objects using **prefetch_related** operation. But in my use case, i wanted to select all the obejects from ModelA and only one(or some) related row from ModelB objects which satisfies certain conditions.

For example:

ModelA.objects.prefetch_related('modelB_set') where modelB__is_open = True
something like that.

The expected output is:

```
[{
    columnA : 1
    created : 'time'
    modelsets :[{
        columnB : 1
        is_open = True
        created = 'time'
    },{
        columnB : 2
        is_open = True
        created = 'time'
    }

},{
    columnA : 2
    created : 'time'
    modelsets :[{
        columnB : 3
        is_open = True
        created = 'time'
    }    
}]
```

I'm tired of googling about this, any links for the better understanding of Django ORM querying would be much appreciable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [Prefetch()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) object

```
queryset_b = Model_B.objects.filter(is_open=True)
result=Model_A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('modelsets', queryset=queryset_b))
```

Comment: i tried using this. But it says _Cannot find 'modelB_set' on ModelA object, 'modelB_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()_. Should i have to do something in Models.py to reflect this?

Comment: @nithinks oh, you are using related_name, then try this: `Prefetch('modelsets', queryset=queryset_b)`

Comment: That helped. Thanks a lot!